# How can I plot complex functions which take small values?

Tags: plotting, graphics, special-functions, complex

I would like to know, how can I plot some functions that have oscillating behavior
each function can be plot independent. The goal is to show both oscillations even is they are very small values.

[image]

This is the code

```
g1 = 1/(Sqrt[10] \[Pi]) (1/16 + I/16) E^(-(1/20)
 I \[Pi] (400 + L^2)) (Erfi[((1/4 + I/4) (20 - L))/Sqrt[
 10 \[Pi]]] + Erfi[((1/4 + I/4) (20 + L))/Sqrt[10 \[Pi]]] - 
Erfi[((1/4 + I/4) (20 - Sqrt[1 + L^2]))/Sqrt[10 \[Pi]]] - 
Erfi[((1/4 + I/4) (20 + Sqrt[1 + L^2]))/Sqrt[10 \[Pi]]])

g2 =  Exp[I Pi/4] ((FresnelC[ 1/Sqrt[2 \[Pi]]   (k L )/Sqrt[k R]] + 
I  FresnelS[ 1/Sqrt[2 \[Pi]]   (k L )/Sqrt[k R]])^2)
```

Using the following code for plot

```
Plot[{Re[1/(
Sqrt[10] \[Pi]) (1/16 + I/16) E^(-(1/20)
   I \[Pi] (400 + L^2)) (Erfi[((1/4 + I/4) (20 - L))/Sqrt[
   10 \[Pi]]] + Erfi[((1/4 + I/4) (20 + L))/Sqrt[10 \[Pi]]] - 
  Erfi[((1/4 + I/4) (20 - Sqrt[1 + L^2]))/Sqrt[10 \[Pi]]] - 
  Erfi[((1/4 + I/4) (20 + Sqrt[1 + L^2]))/Sqrt[10 \[Pi]]])],Re[E^((I \[Pi])/
4) (FresnelC[L/(2 Sqrt[5])] + I FresnelS[L/(2 Sqrt[5])])^2]}, {L, 0, 10}]
```

I used the following command without any output WorkingPrecision ->30 and  PlotRange -> All

Comment: What are `k` and `R` in your `g2`?

Comment: This was a typo, k and R are constant and they can take positive values.

Comment: `LogPlot[{Re[1/(
      Sqrt[10] \[Pi]) (1/16 + I/16) E^(-(1/20)
          I \[Pi] (400 + L^2)) (Erfi[((1/4 + I/4) (20 - L))/Sqrt[
            10 \[Pi]]] + Erfi[((1/4 + I/4) (20 + L))/Sqrt[10 \[Pi]]] - 
        Erfi[((1/4 + I/4) (20 - Sqrt[1 + L^2]))/Sqrt[10 \[Pi]]] - 
        Erfi[((1/4 + I/4) (20 + Sqrt[1 + L^2]))/Sqrt[10 \[Pi]]])], 
  Re[E^((I \[Pi])/
       4) (FresnelC[L/(2 Sqrt[5])] + 
       I FresnelS[L/(2 Sqrt[5])])^2]}, {L, 0, 10}]` shows that these functions have their ranges of fifferent orders.

Comment: That is a good suggestion to consider